# How to build a hierarchy in tree table based on the field value and make child selection possible in SAPUI5

Tags: tree, sapui5, treetable, treetableview

I am using tree table for my app

[image]

and I need the same functionality which is shown on picture, but using OData. The problem is that I can not build hierarchy in view.xml
ot should I write mapping programmatically in controller.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to create odata services which is included HierarchyLevel and ParentNodeID fields.

You can check [OData Annotations TreeBinding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.table.TreeTable/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.TreeTable.ODataAnnotationsTreeBinding) sample.

Comment: and what if in my odata model there are no such parameters as hierarchylevel?

Comment: You have to redefine the `DEFINE` method of your `MPC_EXT` class.

Comment: @Marc can you please explain

Comment: odata is from SaaS system SuccessFactors and service is not available for editing

Comment: In your question you said nothing about SF. Maybe you should provide more details. I have no experience with SF but shouldn't it be possible to extend or inherit from the original service?